The margins are too large when using grid.arrange or ggarrange to combine images
The interval between pictures are too large.
The problem is shown in the picture.

the data is here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vD399eRG8ZMP43YMtBsoYutEnhoujcYf/view?usp=sharing
My attempts:

Tried using 3 syntax to combine images like:
grid.arrange();plot_grid();ggarrange()


Adjusted the margins of plot by adjusting:
plot.margin()



But none of these methods reduced the margins. Does anyone know the reason for this issue?
The following are my coding:
library("sf")
library("sp")
library("ggplot2")
library("gridExtra")
library("cowplot")
library("ggpubr")

##data is provided in Google drive

coordinates(data) <- ~Lon + Lat
proj4string(data) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
data <- st_as_sf(data)


t1 <- ggplot() +
  
  geom_sf(data = data,alpha= 0.8) +
  
  coord_sf(xlim = c(120, 122), ylim = c(22, 25.2)) +
  
  labs(title = "Jan") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
    panel.grid = element_blank(),
    axis.text.x = element_blank(),
    axis.text.y = element_blank(),
    legend.position = "none",
    plot.background = element_rect(color = "blue"),
    panel.border = element_rect(color = "red", fill = "NA"),
    plot.margin = unit(c(0.1, -5, 0.1, -5), "mm")
  )


grid.arrange(t1, t1, t1, t1, ncol = 2)
plot_grid(t1, t1, t1, t1, ncol = 2, align = "v", rel_widths = c(1, 1), axis = "tb")
ggarrange(t1, t1, t1, t1)


For troubleshooting, perhaps you could add plot.background = element_rect(colour = "black", fill=NA) to your plot in the theme section and show that. I suspect the plot is wider than you intended.

I have added
plot.background = element_rect(colour = "black", fill=NA)
The plot width is not wide, but they seperated too farly.

Can you make your output taller / narrower? It sounds like the coord_sf limits you have create a narrow plot, but your output is more than 2x that width (compared to the height).
